# How to remove user from list in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have implemented a confirm button where the confirm button will remove a user from the list. But for some reason, it does not remove the user from the list. Can anyone check my js code to see what I have done wrong.

> Here is my code

```
$scope.doDelete = function(user) {
    var index = $scope.userInfo.users.indexOf(user);
    $scope.userInfo.users.splice(index, 1);
    $window.location.href = '#/user';
}
```

> html

```
<button class="delete" ng-click="doDelete(person)">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: What does index log out before you splice? What does your array look like?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Sorry, I can't understand what you've just said. You want me to `console.log(indexOf);` ?

Comment: After `index` is assigned (the line below) do `console.log(index)` and make sure you're passing a valid index to splice. It will also help to see what `$scope.userInfo.users` logs out as well

Comment: So, I get a the  `index` id number. Such as 1.

Comment: For instance when I click on the first user, it gives me 0

Comment: Hmm, should be working fine. Can you make a runnable example reproducing the issue?

Comment: It doesn't "work" because you reload the page with ```$windows.location.href```. But you're doing it right. Just you're reloading your page, so the data is reinitialised

Comment: @Zooly But, when deletes, I want to go to the home page, while on the home page when refreshing I don't want the user back once more with PUT.

Comment: Check my full code: https://codeshare.io/5okYJr

Comment: Demos : http://plnkr.co/edit/ZdShIA?p=preview

Comment: @codelover I know that demo. I tried, and did not work. Check out my full js code in codeshare link in this comments above.

Comment: Please share html code.I think have problem in html code.

Comment: I did in codeshare

Comment: @codelover was the problem in `home.html`

Comment: @codelover Any solutions?

Comment: @Zooly Did you guys find any solutions to my code in codeshare?

Comment: `BillyJr` You must place you full code in your question (or paste the plunker/fiddle/etc link)! If isn't, @ChrisHalcrow answer should be accepted.

Comment: @BillyJr. I don't really understand. Where is filled your userInfo array in your codeshare ?

Answer (score 2):

You remove the item using:

```
$scope.userInfo.users.splice(index, 1);
```

This only removes it in memory (this change isn't persisted). You then reload the page using:

```
$window.location.href = '#/user';
```

So your array will be reset back to what it was before you removed the item.

Comment: should I erase what I have in doDelete Function and just paste the one you wrote?

Comment: if yes, it still does not answered my question

Comment: I want the changes to take place

Comment: Nowhere are you showing how you get `$scope.userInfo.users` in the first place or even what it contains or where it's located. Maybe it's in a different scope altogether, but we can't know that because we are not mind readers.

Comment: The obvious thing to do is `console.log($scope.userInfo.users);
var index = $scope.userInfo.users.indexOf(user);
$scope.userInfo.users.splice(index, 1);
console.log($scope.userInfo.users);` or set a breakpoint, check the value, step forward, check the value.  There is no apparent to why splice wouldn't work in here. So the problem lies with something you haven't shown us.

Comment: @ippi basically, I want to remove the user from the list, and that method shown above, is not doing it

Comment: @ippi How can splice work when you still reload the page the user is gone?

Comment: How to delete the user from the server?

Comment: Do you get the user from an API call? Does your API have any documentation? Are you using say ng-resource?  The standard is to send a call to /api/users/:id using method `DELETE`.

Comment: @ippi Sorry for the late reply. and yes I do get the users from the api call. and yes

Comment: But, I dont want to use the DELETE method, All I want to use is the PUT method